# Possible to have all Airport Extreme traffic go through a VPN?

Tags: airport, vpn

I'm wondering if it's possible (and if so, how to do it) set up my Airport Extreme so that all devices connecting to it have their traffic piped through a VPN. If I have an OpenVPN running on a Linux server outside my home, is it possible to route all traffic through that?

Answer (score 1):

Airport running stock software doesn't have the ability to encrypt traffic on the WAN port. You could set up a server and use that connection to establish a VPN and have the AirPort WAN connect directly to the server - but that would require a computer on the local ethernet upstream of the AirPort wan port.